# Android version stable version?

Tags: android-versions

I do not use my android phone for anything but making phone calls and browsing the web not logged into anything.

Is there an Android phone version or phone that is not upgradable.  I have noticed as the phone upgrades on both my iPhone and Android the versions of the phone gets slower.

Maybe android go or android one?

The Google Pixel works because you can install any ROM but is slightly to expensive.

Comment: That's the first time I hear someone complain that there *are* updates. That's a novum. Unless you buy a flagship device, updates being available are rather exceptional. Well, and if you insist, you can ignore update announcements and simply not install them.

Comment: @Izzy that is exactly what I do my iPhone mjcro updates auto install on Android

Comment: Urgs, it shouldn't do that… But if it does, I've no idea how it could be prevented.

Comment: Oneplus are a decent solution.